# Why is it called Even HaEzer?

Tags: names, tur

The session of Tur that deals with laws of marriage and divorce is called Even HaEzer (the stone of help). Does anyone know why did he called this session like this? What does it mean?

Answer (score 12):

Even Ha'Ezer contains *halachot* about "דיני אישות", so it would seem that the name is a play on words from "אעשה לו עזר כנגדו" which describes Hashem's creation of Chava (and women in general).

The phrase itself is mentioned twice in Shmuel 1 ([4, 1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t08a04.htm) and [7, 12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t08a07.htm)). It is indeed a "stone of help" - that's how Shmuel called it to signify "עד הנה עזרנו ה'", "until this spot Hashem helped us".

Comment: I didnt get it the play on words… how is אעשה לו עזר כנגדו any similar with אבן העזר?

Comment: The play on words is on "עזר". The Tur took the name of a place from Shmuel, "אבן העזר", for his *halachot* on things that relate to (mostly) women, who are described as "עזר כנגדו" in Bereshit.

Comment: Ok but where does the “even” part come from?

Comment: @aron women are called "even" - anyone know where? Maybe a play on "bina" or "banyan"

Comment: @Aron The Tur simply named his books with phrases out of the bible that relate to the subjects therein ("חושן משפט" because *mishpat* is related to *mamonot*, "אורח חיים" because it talks about a person's day and year, etc.). He picked "Even Ha'Ezer" because it relates to women who are named "עזר כנגדו".

Comment: Who am I to argue with Tur, but if i would pick a bible phrase i think "Ezer Keneged" would make way more sense to me.

Comment: `(and women in general).` source?

Comment: @mevaqesh Common sense.. Do we look upon Adam and Chava as just two private people, or as the basis/mold of all future humanity?

Comment: @Cauthon What may be common sense to you may not be common sense to others. Accordingly, when making assumptions it is worthwhile to make note of this.

Answer (score 8):

In the [introduction to טור חושן משפט (*Tur Choshen Mishpat*)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44265&pgnum=3), it says:

> והטור השלישי **אבן העזר** שם עשיתי לאדם עזר כנגדו גם כשלחה גרש איך יגרשנה מנגדו וקראתיו אבן העזר יען כי הוא להועיל גם לעזר:‏

In my translation:

> And the third column ***'Even ha-'Ezer***, there I made for man a help opposite him (based on [Bereshit 2:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm#18)), and as he might send her, how he may divorce her from before him, and I called it *'Even ha-'Ezer* ("the stone of help", based on [Shemuel I 7:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a07.htm#12)), as it is to be of use and of help.